# Selector error when trying to initialize

Tags: iphone, objective-c

m_NetworkController is my network class and SelDataRecivedError is member of type SEL
now if i am trying to initialize this selector member from other class like this:

```
m_NetworkController.SelDataRecivedError = NSSelectorFromString(@"DataRecivedErrorFromServer");
```

i am getting the error 
`-[NCcontroller setSelDataRecivedError:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3e010c0

what i am missing here?
i have property and @synthesize for the SelDataRecivedError

Comment: can you accept the answer so that this doesn't get revived like today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you try to retain selector?

property should look like this:

@property (assign) SEL SelDataRecivedError;

Comment: Since `SEL` is not an object type, `assign` is the default set semantic (and the only one that makes any sense).

Answer (score 0):

got it.
sorry 
the problem was with @synthesize